# How to resolve org.xml.sax.SAXException in Spring Soap Webservice Client?

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, soap

I followed the steps mentioned in http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html using HTTP transports. My codes is as follows:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessageFactory;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceMessageSender;

@Component
public class blahClient {

@Autowired
private final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new                                  WebServiceTemplate();

public void setDefaultUri(String defaultUri) {
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
}

// send to an explicit URI
public void customSendAndReceive() {


    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(MESSAGE));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(webServiceTemplate.getDefaultUri(),source, result);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}

private static final String MESSAGE = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ser=\"http://service.blah.internal.blah.com\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ser:getblahData><request><caller_id>loginapp</caller_id><content>1067857</content><locale></locale><output>XML, Formatted</output><security_token>vz37ahzcwzakua3z9q2zno66e4xy6wyg8oxh6xn7bordkl</security_token></request></ser:getblahData></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";


public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntactwsClient blahClient = new blahClient();
    blahClient .setDefaultUri("http://blah.com/blah/blahService");
    blahClient .customSendAndReceive();
}
}
```

It gives me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:774)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:600)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:492)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:436)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:421)
at com.blah.internal.blah.service.IntactwsClient.customSendAndReceive(IntactwsClient.java:35)
at com.blah.internal.blah.service.IntactwsClient.main(IntactwsClient.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I have checked the SOAP call from SoapUI with the same XML message and it works fine. I am not able to diagnose the reason for this error. I do not need to create a class and use objects marshalled from response as I only need one value to be parsed from response. I was hoping WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult will work like Soap RestTemplate and yield a response which can be parsed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);    

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

I think these 2  lines are responsible for the exception. Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html)

You are trying to convert StreamResult object , directly into string.
Instead you should be using your output stream (System.out) into string.

Try this,

```
System.out.toString();
System.out.println(result.toString());    //Remove this line
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I removed the new line characters. Still got same error. I removed the extra spaces too and yet the same error. Can it  be the case that the SOAP service is designed in such a way that it would only work with webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive using classes and objects?

Comment: Thanks for looking into. I realized that I was converting object to string. But the exception occurs at the  SOAP service call at this line - webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(webServiceTemplate.getDefaultUri(),source, result);

Comment: Can you just paste whatever present in MESSAGE string in soap ui from your code, and see, is it working?

Comment: I printed the MESSAGE string and used it in soap ui. I get the result message as expected.